# Repopulate a div after an ajax form is submitted using ajax (I think!)

Tags: php, ajax

I have a table with a bunch of products from my database table. Each product has an update button which will produce a populated form via ajax for the user to ammend any details they wish.

On submit, I want to update the database and then return back to the page I was just on showing real-time updating data. With anything else I do, I send back a view to the ajax success function and it gets displayed. Only I can't seem to do it with this. I take the action and method out of my form tag and let an ajax function handle it, but it doesn't return a view, it just displays the view only, whereas I want my div to go into a specific div on the existing page

```
/*****  submit update form  *****/
$(document).on('click', '#updateSubmit', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'products/updateProduct',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#viewProducts').fadeIn(1000, function(){
                $(this).html(data);
            //  THIS IS WHERE I WANT MY VIEW TO BE RETURNED TO(the #viewProducts).  CAN THAT BE DONE?
            })
        } // end success
    }); // end ajax 
}); // end submit event
```

Comment: whats problem in this ? it will show the content in #viewProducts

Comment: `but it doesn't return a view, it just displays the view only, whereas I want my div to go into a specific div on the existing page` Can you clarify your question?

Comment: ther is no problem if you havent used same id again  which should not be

Comment: I am wanting my php function to retun data to the ajax call and display in  the #viewProducts div. i am not getting anything returned

Comment: My database is getting updated

Comment: NullPointer is right. If you are submitting the update form, your db is getting updated but not the view so you should echo your db tables everytime on submission of update form otherwise nothing will be updated.

Comment: Do I leave in the form action and method in the form tags?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

`url: '/products/updateProduct'` in place of `url: 'products/updateProduct'`

if still not works try to use full path in place of relative path............